# PHP remove everything afer last colon of string

Tags: php, regex

I have few strings, where words are separated with colon. And I need to remove everything after last colon AND the last colon. I've found only solutions, which *work the other way*, remove everything before and keep the last colon and last word. Like this:

```
$link = trim(substr($link, strrpos($link, ':') + 1));
```

Strings looks like this:

```
Dashboard:Default:default
Construction:List:workflow
Construction:List:default
```

Comment: What you want as output from string?

Comment: @dhruvjadia I need only
`Dashboard:Default
Construction:List
Construction:List`

Comment: What's the problem with `var_dump(substr($link, 0, strrpos($link, ':')));`? [PHP Docs reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker that works great, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@HS1993 you can also achieve it by substr() and strrpos, substr() will extract the required part of string and strrpos() will find the last occurrence of ":"  like:

```
<?php
    $str = 'Dashboard:Default:default';
    echo substr($str, 0, strrpos($str,":"));
```

> output: Dashboard:Default

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex for matching all text after last colon (including the last colon):

```
/:(\w)*$/
```

- `:` looks for a colon (:)
- `(\w)*` matches a text with any number of characters
- `$` denotes end of string

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/7eX8SS/2/

PHP:

```
$link = 'Construction:List:default';
$pattern = '/:(\w)*$/';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $link);
// Output: Construction:List
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/UhRcaB

Comment: Can I have your email, please? awaiting your response. kind regards

Comment: Hey @Nofuzy just got this message. degant7[at]gmail[dot]com

Comment: Hi @degant, I just sent you an email. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = preg_replace("/:([^:]*)$/m", "", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you out, Here we are using `explode`, `unset` and `implode`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/787562)

**Solution 1:**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string='Dashboard:Default:default';
$result=explode(":", $string);
unset($result[count($result)-1]);
echo $result=implode(":",$result);
```

**Solution 2:**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string='Dashboard:Default:default';
echo substr_replace($string,"",strrpos($string, ':'));
```

**Output:**
`Dashboard:Default`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code. Maybe it'll help you.

```
<?php
$string = 'Dashboard:Default:default';
$strParts = explode(':', $string);

array_pop($strParts);

echo implode(':',$strParts);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$link = 'Dashboard:Default:default';
$link = substr($link, 0, strrpos($link, ':'));

echo $link;
```